# Remove NAs in row, and move the cell on the right were the NA was located in R also unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, na, average-precision

OK, so I have a data frame in R like this

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3)
c1 <- c( 1, 1, NA)
c2 <- c(NA, NA, 5)
c3 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
c4 <- c(2, NA, 5)
c5 <- c(5, 7, 3)

df <- data.frame(ID, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
```

So, this is what I'm looking for

```
1. Treat every row as a vector
2. Be able to remove all NAs in every row/vector
3. In a given row there can't be repeated values (expect for ID vs a number in other cell)
4. I'm looking to "cut" this row/vector.  I don't need 5 values just 2.
```

I'm doing this for a MAP@k metric, so the order of the numbers (the one on the left is more importante than the next one) son it's important to keep the order.

This is the output that I'm looking for

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3)
c1 <- c(1, 1, 5)
c2 <- c(2, 7, 3)

df2 <- data.frame(ID, c1, c2)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

We loop through the rows of 'df' (using `apply` with `MARGIN` as 1), remove the `NA` elements (`!is.na(x)`) and get the `unique` values.  Then, if the length of the elements are not the same, the output will be a `list` ('lst').  We use `lengths` to get the `length` of each `list` element`, get the`min`of it, based on it we subset the`list`elements and`cbind` with the first column 'ID'.

```
 lst <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)]))
 dfN <- cbind(df[1], do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) x[seq(min(lengths(lst)))])))
 colnames(dfN)[-1] <- paste0("c", colnames(dfN)[-1])
 dfN
 #  ID c1 c2
 #1  1  1  2
 #2  2  1  7
 #3  3  5  3
```

NOTE: If the `length` of `unique` elements are the same in each row (after removing the `NA`), the output will be a `matrix`.  Just transpose the output and `cbind` with the first column.

---

Or another option is `data.table` which should be very efficient.

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(df), id.var="ID", na.rm=TRUE)[, 
          .(value = unique(value), n = seq(uniqueN(value))), ID]
dcast(dM[dM[, n1 := min(tabulate(ID))][, .I[1:.N <=n1] , ID]$V1],
           ID~paste0("c", n), value.var="value")
#  ID c1 c2
#1:  1  1  2
#2:  2  1  7
#3:  3  5  3
```

Comment: I'm about to try it my actual code, Thanks! You're amazing!

Comment: I think the long-then-wide paradigm is the way to go for this sort of problem. It scales nicely and can be converted to dplyr/data.table/base R/sql whatever relatively easily.

Comment: I used the data.table idea and translate it into dplyr/tidyr.  It works!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but should be efficient (chewed through 3M records in about 20secs and 300K in < 2 secs):

```
sel <- !is.na(df[-1])
tmp <- unique(data.frame(ID=df$ID[row(df[-1])[sel]], c=df[-1][sel]))
tmp$time <- ave(tmp$ID, tmp$ID, FUN=seq_along)

reshape(tmp[tmp$time <= 2,], idvar="ID", direction="wide", sep="")

#  ID c1 c2
#1  1  1  2
#2  2  1  7
#3  3  5  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on akrun data.table idea, I translated the data.table code to dplyr/tidyr (is easier for me to read, that's all).  Here is the code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_tidy <- df %>%
gather(importance, val, c1:c5) %>% 
na.omit %>% 
arrange(ID, importance) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
distinct(ID, val) %>%
mutate(place = seq_len(n())) %>%
filter(place <= 2) %>%
mutate(place = paste("c", place, sep="")) %>%
select(-importance) %>%
spread(place, val)
```

Thank you akrun and thelatemail !